# Regarding efficiency: Isn’t .filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get) better than .flatmap(Optional::stream)?

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

`Optional::stream` returns a Stream containing the value if it is present and else an empty stream. So for a `Stream<Optional<T>> optionals`,

```
optionals.flatMap(Optional::stream)
```

returns a `Stream<T>` containing the present values of all optionals. But regarding the functionality behind it, I‘m unsure how efficient it is to create an own stream for every present value and then flatMapping the stream of streams.

But even in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#stream--) this is mentioned as an intended use.

Why isn‘t streaming a stream of optionals highly inefficient compared with first filtering all present values and then mapping the optionals to their values?

Comment: It's not clear that a stream that contains at most one element should be expensive to create or access.  A stream of such streams is not likely to be more expensive than a stream of the original `Optional` instances.

Comment: As-is, I would say it is a matter of personal choice as long as we do not have an actual performance problem(`...stream().filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get)` vs. `...stream().flatMap(Optional::stream)`). Remember that ["*premature optimization is the root of all evil*" -- Donald Ervin Knuth: *Computer Programming as an Art* (1974), p. 671](https://dl.acm.org/ft_gateway.cfm?id=361612&ftid=289767)

Comment: You (or somebody) need to come up with a benchmark. I don't have numbers to back up my claim, but I remember seeing a severe performance hit when using the `flatMap` option. I guess the main factor is lots of new `Stream` instances being created and then garbage collected. And each of those single-item streams then needs to be iterated (by obtaining its iterator instance) one by one

Comment: Remember that "not considering efficiency is the root of waste and the path to climate armageddon" -- Anonish (2023) ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I got curious and wrote a simple micro-benchmark using [JMH](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh).

And it turns out that there is a quite severe performance penalty for using `flatMap(Optional::stream)` over `filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get)`.

Java 16 introduced `mapMulti` which is similar to `flatMap` in usage and has performance characteristics very close to those of `filter`/`map`.

Each of my benchmark methods takes a list of `Optional<Integer>` and computes the sum of all present values.

I implemented three approaches:

1. [`flatMap`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) as posited the question
2. [`filter`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter(java.util.function.Predicate)) and [`map`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) as described in the question
3. [`mapMulti`](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer)) introduced in JDK 16.

Note that I did **not** make use of the `flatMapToInt` or `mapMultiToInt` methods, which are probably more efficient, because I didn't want to focus on the streams-over-wrapper objects aspect and just compare the usage of streams over `Optional` objects.

For all approaches I ran the benchmark with a full list (all values present), a half empty list (every second value present), and an entirely empty list (each optional is empty). The lists are all the same length (arbitrarily picked 10 000 elements each).

The unit for the values is us/op (microseconds per operation, meaning one full stream evaluation).

| Approach | Full List | Half Empty List | Empty List |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `flatMap` | 207.219 ± 1.176 | 175.355 ± 4.955 | 142.986 ± 2.821 |
| `filter`/`map` | 12.856 ± 0.375 | 12.086 ± 0.451 | 6.856 ± 0.143 |
| `mapMulti` | 13.990 ± 0.353 | 11.685 ± 0.276 | 7.034 ± 0.199 |

Note that the absolute numbers here are specific to my machine running JDK 16 and are mostly irrelevant anyway. The relative differences are what is important here.

It seems the `flatMap` approach is both significantly slower and more variable. If I had to guess the variability comes from increased GC pressure caused by all the `Stream` objects created, even for empty results.

**Disclaimer**: this is obviously just a single made-up example being tested and the benchmark hasn't been peer-reviewed (yet), so don't take these results for granted without further investigation.

Full benchmark code below (note that I turned down some iterations/runtimes to get responses in a reasonable time and hard-coded to use 4 threads. Adapt as required.)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@Fork(value = 1, warmups = 0)
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 5)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 5)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
@Threads(4)
public class MyBenchmark {

    @State(Scope.Benchmark)
    public static class MyLists {
        private static final int LIST_SIZE = 10_000;

        public final List<Optional<Integer>> allValues;
        public final List<Optional<Integer>> halfEmpty;
        public final List<Optional<Integer>> allEmpty;

        public MyLists() {
            List<Optional<Integer>> allValues = new ArrayList<>(LIST_SIZE);
            List<Optional<Integer>> halfEmpty = new ArrayList<>(LIST_SIZE);
            List<Optional<Integer>> allEmpty = new ArrayList<>(LIST_SIZE);
            for (int i = 0; i < LIST_SIZE; i++) {
                Optional<Integer> o = Optional.of(i);
                allValues.add(o);
                halfEmpty.add(i % 2 == 0 ? o : Optional.empty());
                allEmpty.add(Optional.empty());
            }
            this.allValues = Collections.unmodifiableList(allValues);
            this.halfEmpty = Collections.unmodifiableList(halfEmpty);
            this.allEmpty = Collections.unmodifiableList(allEmpty);
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    public long filter_and_map_allValues(MyLists lists) {
        return filterAndMap(lists.allValues);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public long filter_and_map_halfEmpty(MyLists lists) {
        return filterAndMap(lists.halfEmpty);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public long filter_and_map_allEmpty(MyLists lists) {
        return filterAndMap(lists.allEmpty);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public long flatMap_allValues(MyLists lists) {
        return flatMap(lists.allValues);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public long flatMap_halfEmpty(MyLists lists) {
        return flatMap(lists.halfEmpty);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public long flatMap_allEmpty(MyLists lists) {
        return flatMap(lists.allEmpty);
    }


    @Benchmark
    public long mapMulti_allValues(MyLists lists) {
        return mapMulti(lists.allValues);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public long mapMulti_halfEmpty(MyLists lists) {
        return mapMulti(lists.halfEmpty);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public long mapMulti_allEmpty(MyLists lists) {
        return mapMulti(lists.allEmpty);
    }

    private long filterAndMap(List<Optional<Integer>> input) {
        return input.stream().filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
    }

    private long flatMap(List<Optional<Integer>> input) {
        return input.stream().flatMap(Optional::stream).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
    }

    private long mapMulti(List<Optional<Integer>> input) {
        // Unfortunately the type witness <Integer> is necessary here, as type inference would otherwise make mapMulti produce a Stream<Object>.
        return input.stream().<Integer>mapMulti(Optional::ifPresent).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
    }
}
```

Comment: With JDK 16, a new variant is possible, [`mapMulti(Optional::ifPresent)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapMulti(java.util.function.BiConsumer))

Comment: @Holger: thanks, I hadn't known of that one yet, I've added that to the benchmark. It seems to perform almost as well as `filter`/`map`.

Comment: We can also unbox in-place using `input.stream().mapMultiToInt((o,c) -> o.ifPresent(c::accept)) .sum()` but I’m afraid it won’t improve the performance due to the capturing lambda expression (though it might when Escape Analysis works good enough).

Comment: @Holger: I saw that this is an option but 1.) didn't quite know how to use it and 2.) didn't want to focus too much on the unboxing aspect (as that'd change the focus of the question/answer). It's easier to compare the results when all three approaches do the same thing.